Azure Database for Postgres Restore to point in time is not working properly
I have an Azure Database for Postgres instance that I wanted to roll back a few hours (or days) to grab some rows that I deleted. Using these instructions I tried to roll back one hour, a few hours, and a few days, but in all cases I see that the new database is not restored, I see the same data that I have on main database. New data that is coming to the database is also visible on restored instance.
Restore to full backup is working as expected. Do you know if there is some bug with restore to point in time on Azure? Or maybe there is some configuration I need to add to make it work?
I see that I'm not the only one with such issue, but I wasn't able to find solution to this.
